# is there any difference between ip address of a website and ip address of the webserver which is hosting the website?

Tags: networking

I am new in networking. Recenty learning about DNS. My question is when DNS mechanism obtain the ip address of a website, say www.google.com, is that ip address is the ip address of the webserver in which Google.com belongs? Or it is just a key ip address so that if we tell the internet the internet will show the page but absolutely no connection with the ip address of the webserver which is hosting google.com?

Comment: In most real world cases for large websites, the IP address(es) of the site would be for the load balancer or reverse proxy, not the actual web servers. Often the webservers won't even have public IP addresses. It's only in the simplest setups that you'll actually be connecting directly to the IP address of the web server.

Comment: For your example of the Google site. The public IP addresses you connect to, will be routing the requests to any one of thousands of load balanced servers. These servers will be in private subnets and will not have public IP addresses.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The website address, say `www.google.com` is a human-readable address which is linked to an IP address.  An (v4) IP address looks something like `52.174.110.151`.  When you browse to a site, your web browser asks a DNS server to lookup the web address and give it the IP address for the server.  The IP address is then used to call for the website.  Every web server has a fixed IP address (I won't get into the more complex setup of load-balancing and multiple IP addresses).

If you have the IP address for a web server, you can browse to it directly, as in http://52.174.110.151.

Comment: "_(I won't get into the more complex setup of load-balancing and multiple IP addresses)._" Or, in the case of Google, anycast.